# Cannot convert List<String> to List<Column> in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a list of strings (`List<String> cols`) into a list of columns (`List<Column> groupBycols`) like this :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
List<Column> groupBycols = cols.stream()
                    .map(functions::col).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It works when JAVA 11 installed but when JAVA 8 only is installed it doesn't and suggests rather converting into a `List<Object>`
How could i do that in JAVA 8 ?

Thanks

Comment: " it doesn't and suggests " ... what is "it" here? Your IDE?

Comment: Yes, my IDE !!!

Comment: I'm not sure what causes this, but it would help if you'd add the Spark version you are using because you should be careful to operate on matching Spark and Java versions. It seems like your Spark version is a bit too "recent" and uses methods that are not quite applicable in Java 8.

Comment: Spark version is `3.1.1`

Comment: Does your program executes with Java 8 even if you don't fulfill the suggestion to covert the list into a list of `Object`? Or is it an actual error that stops the project from building?

Comment: it is an actual error that stops the project from building

Comment: Have you tried to turn the list into `List<Object>` and afterwards casting the elements in `Column`? Or have you tried using the `List<String> cols` in a way where each element will be specified as a column like this `col("col0")` so you will have something like a for loop to iterate the list and for each element you can write `col(elem)` (`elem` being each element for every iteration)?

Comment: no i didn't try that

Comment: `Change project compliance to JRE 1.8` suggestion solved the issue